# Without loss of generality let's assume that sequence is strictly decreasing...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question considering 'without loss of generality'. In one proof on my lecture we assume that sequence is strictly decreasing. We know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_{n}}=-\infty$ so I think that the other option here is that the sequence is nonincreasing. The thing is I can't show that we can assume this without losing generality, it's kind of natural but I can't form any formal thought.

EDIT:
We also know that
$a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You need to provide more information. Without more information about the sequence (just that it tends to - infinity) we are not justified in considering only strictly decreasing sequences, as there are plenty of non monotonic sequences which tend to - infinity, with no easy and immediate way to generalize a proof from the monotonic to non the non monotonic case

Comment: I added one information but that's all I have...

Comment: If I had to guess, they probably used the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$ since the sequence converges and $\tilde{a}_n = \sup_{k \geq n} a_k$ is a decreasing sequence. However, it is not necessarily strictly decreasing so more work would have to be done to pass to a strictly decreasing subsequence.

Comment: @DanielApsley $\bar{a}_n+\frac1n$ would then be a strictly decreasing sequence

Answer (score 1):

You can have a sequence which increases and decreases infinitely often but still has a limit of $-\infty$.

For example with alternating steps of $+1$ and $-2$:

$$-1, 0,-2,-1,-3,-2,-4,-3, -5, -4,\ldots$$

where the $n$th term is close to $-\frac{n}{2}$, the limit is clearly $-\infty$.

Whether this matters in a particular case, or whether there is no loss of generality in assuming the sequence is strictly decreasing, will depend on the particular circumstances.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused... In the proof we use this decreasing sequence to generate decreasing family of sets. How can I show that if theorem is true for decreasing sequence which limit is $-\infty$ then it is true for all sequences which limit is $-\infty$